# How to update a variable inside a function?

Tags: python, scope, global-variables

I have a question about two different ways of writing a piece of code. I want to know whether they are both okay or one is better under some conditions? Basically, is it better to give the variable we want to update to the function or not?

```
def f1(num):
    output.append(num)

output = []
f1(2)
print(output)
```

and

```
def f1(num, output):
    output.append(num)

output = []
f1(2, output)
print(output)
```

Comment: Avoid the first one where possible; mutable global variables are a recipe for confusion and bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, your function works for only adding element to globally defined certain array. And it is not good approach, you cannot use it for another array.

Second one has generic approach which is better. But only one small correction; you have an array named `output`, and you pass it to your function, but you keep its name same in your function. So, for your function, there are two `output` one global and one local, better use different names in this case:

```
output = []

def f1(num, arr):
    arr.append(num)

f1(2, output)
print(output)
```

Please see warning PyCharm shows in same naming case:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider avoiding to use the first example where possible: global variables can be very difficult to work with, generating problems you never find easily. Instead, use the second piece of code.

You could also write something like the following code:

```
output = []

def add(num, listName):
    listName.append(num)

    return listname

for _ in range(5):
    output = add(_, output)

print(output)
```